# Issue while moving file using java.nio

Tags: java, nio

Getting below exception while trying to move a file after renaming it, issue is that it is occurring intermittently i.e. sometimes the code works and sometimes it does not and is not replicable, would be helpful if anyone can provide insight on the same

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /data/Inprocess/DEMO.20191026.csv -> /data/Inprocess/DEMO.20191026.csv.inprogress
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:457)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
```

```
Path fromPath = inputFile.toPath();
Path toPath = new File(inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".inprogress").toPath();
LOGGER.info("Moving file to Path: " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".inprogress");
try {
    Files.move(fromPath, fromPath.resolveSibling(toPath),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle Exception
    throw new TradeProcessorException("Error while marking file Inprogress: ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One difference between the old `File` (pure disk files/directories) and the newer, more powerful `Path` is, that the latter maintains its "file" system (which could be a zip, ram disk, remote disk). So once using Path, keep using it.

```
Path fromPath = inputFile.toPath();
String toName = inputFile.getFileName().toString() + ".inprogress";
Path toPath = inputFile.resolveSibling(toName);

LOGGER.info("Moving file to Path: " + toPath);
try {
    Files.move(fromPath, toPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Your usage of resolveSibling seems to add a full path.

(Above the superfluous `.toString()` is just a reminder that `getFileName()` returns a `Path`.)